# Javascript function returning with a hash in the url despite returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this link that is supposed to delete an entry and refresh a div via ajax. However, for some reason it isn't working at all and its just shifting the page up and adding a # to the url.

If I add an alert to output the id and user_id, it shows up and no # is added to the url.

This is the code

```
<script>
    function removeExistingBranch(id,user_id){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url($this->data['controller'].'/RemoveUserBranch/'); ?>",
            data:'id='+id+,
                '&user_id'+user_id,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.loading').show();
            },
            success: function(data){
//                $( "#existing_branch_container" ).load( "<?php echo site_url($this->data['controller']);?>/LoadUserBranches" );
                $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
            },
        });
        return false;
    }
    </script>

<a href="#" onclick="return removeExistingBranch(<?php echo $data['user_branches_id'];?>,<?php echo $user['user_accounts_id'];?>)">Remove</a>
```

Could someone take a look and see if I am missing something?

Comment: Any errors showing in browser console?

Comment: Ah! I did not catch this before. It's showing this Unexpected token ,

Comment: I don't understand how to fulfill the parameter requirements if this error shows though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in the ajax call. Change it

```
data:'id='+id+,'&user_id'+user_id,
```

to

```
data:'id='+id+'&user_id'+user_id,
```

Comment: Or cleaner to use object: `data:{id: id, user_id: user_id},`

Comment: Ah! I just saw that. Thank you!